# First Riddle: manifold of modern world's peace-loving reasons

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

Who am I?

> One of my forms is killed when I'm young, by ramming into myself
>
> But I live long after I die, seeking revenge
>
> The less this world knows about me, the better
>
> For I can heat up and kill in the form which killed the parent's of the temperature man!

**Hint:**

> Antagonistic phenomenon of the question's title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be

> Any radioactive substance

I am killed when I'm young, by ramming into myself

> radioactive decay starts as soon as the radioactive substance exists and is caused by nuclei bumping into one another

But I live long after I die, seeking revenge

> It continues long after it starts

The less this world knows about me, the better

> the energy released in the process is dangerous to humans

For I can heat up and kill in the form which killed the temperature man!

> I'm not sure who this is talking about since Celsius died of Tuberculosis and Fahrenheit died of Mercury poisoning as far as I can tell.

Comment: I had made the edit-"parents of the temperature man" as soon as I posted the question, but my iPad got stuck in the middle so I had to reboot. Sorry for the inconvenience. And the answer is correct!